# Trouble loading Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: system-installation, dell, iso

I've spent the better part of two days trying to load the Ubuntu 22.04.3 live server amd64 ISO via an iDRAC on a Dell R730 server.  It appears that the ISO does not like being loaded via the virtual CD function as I keep getting SQUASHFS errors.

I double checked the checksum of the ISO against the original checksum Ubuntu posts and they match, so it's not a corrupted image.  THe network is inside a firewall that only allows main, multiverse, restricted and universe portions of the Ubuntu repos through.  The image works fine on VM's, just not as a mounted file via an iDRAC.  Is there a version 22.04 that can work as a mounted ISO?

As a sanity check, I loaded Ubuntu 20.04.5 live server amd64 ISO in the same manner and had no problems.

Comment: UPDATE: I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 server outside the firewall, via an iDrac on a  R730 and it worked too.  It's looking more and more like it must be another repo that it need access to.

Comment: UPDATE AGAIN: I managed to get a copy of Ubuntu 22.04 server on DVD, it installed without problem.  Yet a copy of the exact same ISO (copied from the DVD), loaded via an iDRAC, produced SQUASHFS errors.

So to recap, iDRAC's work at loading Ubuntu 22.04 when directly accessing the internet, but not when a firewall is blocking out all but main, multiverse, restricted and universe portions of the Ubuntu repos.